# If I change job whilst my ESTA is still valid do I need to reapply or change this info within my ESTA details?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, esta

I am going to be changing jobs soon and plan on visiting my girlfriend (in the US) later in the year.

Do I need to make any changes to my ESTA information or reapply since this information is used when making an ESTA application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a change of place of employment is not listed by CBP as a reason to change your ESTA.  You can visit the [CBP webpage on changing ESTA information](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1073/~/apply-or-change-information-in-the-electronic-system-for-travel-authorization) for more information.  The required reasons to apply for a change:

> If you obtain a new passport or change your name, gender or country of citizenship, you will be required to apply for a new travel authorization. This is also required if one of your answers to any of the VWP eligibility questions changes.

The VWP eligibility questions include:

> You must also answer the Visa Waiver Program (VWP) eligibility questions regarding communicable diseases, arrests and convictions for certain crimes, and past history of visa revocation or deportation, among others.

Change of employment does not meet the level of requiring a new ESTA.